# Do old, dry boards continue to warp?

Tags: deck

I have a number of 2x12’s that have been exposed to Florida weather for about 8 years.

Because they have not warped, I wonder if I can expect them to remain relatively straight as deck boards?

*I do not know the wood species, not yellow pine though.*

Comment: Let us know in another 8 years.

Comment: When used in the weather even if totally dry like your boards are by now they can still cup when exposed. Looking at the end grain if the rings in the wood are curved you want any cup shape pointing down so the wood will not hold water and further cup. This can happen to fully dry boards when exposed to the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the wood species boards warp for several reasons. Primarily it's when a difference in moisture loss (or gain) occurs at different areas of the lumber. Grain direction also effects movement.

If your boards have been out of the elements for 8 years and have remained straight then they should remain so. I would be more concerned about the boards decaying at this point. Unless they are protected from rain and sunlight they will decay from fungus, termites and U.V damage.

Place them several inches off the ground with 2 x 4's (stickers ?) spaced about every 3 feet. Stack the boards tightly together (if dry) and than cover with an exterior tarp.

8 years is a lot of time for lumber to remain unscathed from the elements. They should be protected or used.